# Unable to browse some pdfs and docs

Tags: file, iis-6, indexing-service

I have a web site that uses Microsoft Indexing Service to index and query a directory that holds various documents of type pdf, rtf, mht, and doc.  The indexing and querying works well (for the most part); however, some files will load while others will not.

This is a Windows Server 2003 box running the site using IIS 6.

The indexed directory is a sub directory off of the site's root directory (i.e. http://my.domain.com/files/).

The file paths are accurate in the URL; however, I can only access some of the files of each file type.  The files that I cannot access give a 404 File Not Found.  I am able to open all files via windows explorer;however, attempting to open them via a browser over http is hit and miss.

Has anyone experienced this issue and know how to resolve it?  Anyone have any idea why I could access some files but not others?  Does anyone have any recommendations on what to look into to try this (i.e. does owner matter or something like that?)?

---

**EDIT:**
Here is the Request and Response Headers for a bad file:

GET /files/file1.pdf HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/xaml+xml, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-ms-application, application/x-silverlight, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.590; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: my.domain.com

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 1635
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2009 15:38:54 GMT
[typical 404 page markup excluded]

Here is the Request/Response headers for the good file:

GET /files/file2.pdf HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/xaml+xml, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-ms-application, application/x-silverlight, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.590; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: my.domain.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 352464
Content-Type: application/pdf
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Jan 2009 15:27:35 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "74ccc5759375c91:2a47"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2009 15:50:33 GMT

Comment: Directory permissions? (Not sure if all the files are sitting in one place from your description.)

Comment: @Michael Todd Yes, all files are in the same directory so it's not directory level permissions; however, I'm still looking to see if there's any difference between file permissions.  Sadly, haven't found any trends yet.

Comment: That's very odd. A file is a file is a.... IIS shouldn't care what the type is (or anything else about it but permissions), so if it exists, it should be able to serve it. What do the headers say during the request and in the response?

Comment: @Michael Todd Just added them to the description.

Comment: Looks fine (nothing leaps out). As a test, rename one of the "good" files to a temp, then rename a "bad" file to the same name as the "good" file. Can you then grab it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue being at the configuration of IIS.  The Sys admin in charge of the server that was experience this issue made Virtual Directory with the same name as the subdirectory that was being indexed.  When IIS would resolve the path, the documents would be served up from the virtual directory instead of the sub directory like it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, install the most current cumulative security update for Internet Explorer. 
For more technical information about the most current cumulative security update for Internet Explorer, visit the following [Microsoft Web site](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/current.aspx)